# Python generates same uuid over multiple Docker containers

Tags: python, random, bigdata, uuid

I have a service, which generates data, and stores it in Kafka. The service works on 20+ instances in Docker containers. To store data we need to assign a `UUID` for the object, so we can use it right now in the code, and provide relations between different objects in database. But the problem is that Python generates the same uuid too often (like 1 time per hour). By saying 'the same' I mean there is a duplicate uuid in a batch of data. Batches are 15-20k rows, and I insert them every minute pooling the data from Kafka.

The error is

`Key "(uuid)=(4c09ce36-20de-4ea9-b176-8d15eade409e)" already exists.`

but there are no row with such key in the table, so looks like python generated 2 uuids with the same value in a batch.

Below is the function which generates uuid. Rn I use default uuid module

```
async def create_object_from_kwargs(object_: Type[T], **kwargs) -> T:
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if isinstance(v, uuid.UUID):
            kwargs[k] = str(v)

    kwargs['uuid'] = uuid.uuid4().__str__()
    data = {
        'model': object_.__tablename__,
        'data': kwargs
    }
    serialized_data = pickle.dumps(data)
# sending to kafka
    await producer.send_and_wait(KAFKA_NAME, serialized_data)

# getting actual model
    item = object_(**kwargs)

    return item
```

The question is how should I randomize the uuid seed or do something like this to get more random values? Can containers be the reason of the random? Under the hood python's uuid module uses `os.urandom(16)`, which probably uses something like CPU name or something similar to create a random seed, but this kind of information is the same across all the containers.

P.S. I have 150M+ rows in my table, so change to get the duplicate in the table is meager: 4e-31.

Comment: Maybe try one of the others. There's also `.uuid1()`, `.uuid3()`, and `.uuid5()`. They generate uuids from different data.

Answer (score 1):

uuid4 uses a psuedo random generator. As mentioned above by Ouroborus
using .uuid1() would be the most appropriate as it uses host mac address, sequence and time.

also please refer to this:
[page](https://pynative.com/python-uuid-module-to-generate-universally-unique-identifiers/)

best regards